# where I'm doing wrong, can anyone check I'm getting keyerror : 1

Tags: python, csv, oop

```
import csv
year = []
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []
col4 = []
filename = open('data.csv', 'r')
file = csv.DictReader(filename)
for col in file:
    year.append(col['Year (Upto 31st March) (Col.1)'])
    col1.append(col['Central - Motor Vehicle & Accessories - Import Duty (Col.2)'])
    col2.append(col['Central - Tyres and Tubes - Import Duty (Col.4)'])
    col3.append(col['Central - High Speed Diesel Oil - Import Duty (Col.6)'])
    col4.append(col['Central - Motor Spirit - Import Duty (Col.8)'])
    
def column_selection():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        col[i] = [float(j) for j in col[i]]
        for k in range(1, 5):
            a[k] = max(col[i])
def index_printing():
    for i in range(1,5):
        a[i] = col[i].index(a[k])    
        print(year[a[i]])

column_selection()
index_printing()
```

Comment: It's because `col[1]` is not at all the same thing as `col1`.  If you want that to be a list of lists, then make it a list of lists, but remember that lists in Python start numbering from 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  Your code was confusing in how it used the array `a`, but I think this is the gist.  Really, you should have told us what you were trying to do here.

```
import csv
year = []
col = [[],[],[],[]]
filename = open('data.csv', 'r')
file = csv.DictReader(filename)
for column in file:
    year.append(column['Year (Upto 31st March) (Col.1)'])
    col[0].append(column['Central - Motor Vehicle & Accessories - Import Duty (Col.2)'])
    col[1].append(column['Central - Tyres and Tubes - Import Duty (Col.4)'])
    col[2].append(column['Central - High Speed Diesel Oil - Import Duty (Col.6)'])
    col[3].append(column['Central - Motor Spirit - Import Duty (Col.8)'])
    
def column_selection():
    maxes = []
    for i in range(4):
        col[i] = [float(j) for j in col[i]]
        maxes.append( max(col[i]) )
    return maxes

def index_printing(maxes):
    for c,m in zip(col,maxes):
        z = c.index(m)    
        print(year[z])

m = column_selection()
index_printing(m)
```

Comment: what should i do to print the category name like "Central - Tyres and Tubes - Import Duty (Col. 4)" along with year which is going to be printed at last line of code

Comment: `file.fieldnames` has the list of names it read from line 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is occurring because how you have structured the list `col1,col2`... and appending `col list` `to each list`. please try to col list as a nested list and the try to append col list to it as each element of nested list.